# Optimal SQL statement or algorithm for finding Most Popular Category of Items in a Database

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, sorting

Assume an element e.g. a youtube video can be of various categories e.g. music, sports, entertainment.

I want to look through all elements in a database and output an ordered list of the most frequently occurring categories.

**EDIT:** To be specific, There are three relevant database tables. 1) item (name, id) 2) category (name, id) 3) item_category (item_id, category_id)

1) Is there anything more efficient than this?:

```
Pseudocode
foreach (category)
   select all database elements which match that category
   associate category with the number of results from the select query
   return the associative array

 sort the associative array on the values of each category (key)
```

2) What PHP function allows me easily do the sorting of the values of an associative array? Or what SQL allows me do this more efficiently?

Comment: Do you want to do this in the database, or in PHP? The database is typically better suited to filtering and sorting data...

Comment: which ever allows me do it more efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS popularity
FROM categories, views
WHERE views.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY views.category_id
ORDER BY popularity DESC
```

This selects all the categories and orders them from most to least popular.